# How to download a file from aws bucket only by knowing bucket name and object name in python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to download a file from aws bucket ( name known ) and object name know. But access key id and secret key are not known.

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

s3 = boto3.resource(service_name='s3')
s3.Bucket('yz').download_file(Key='keh.docx', Filename='keh.docx')
```

Getting the Following error
NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Is there any way that we can download a file without secret key and access id?

Comment: What is your current python code and why it does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example from the boto3 documentation

```py
Import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file('BUCKET_NAME', 'OBJECT_NAME', 'FILE_NAME')
```

If the file is in a public bucket, you can only use the `request` package.

```py
import queries
url = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/[bucket_name]/[path_to_file]/file'
file = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)
open('./file', 'wb').write(file.content)
```

Comment: Thanks, I am able to download it , but the original file is in pdf or docx format, How to download in that format ? It is getting download in a different format.

Comment: When downloading an image it takes a lot of time using request package, Any other way of downloading the file in fastest way.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there any way that we can download a file without secret key and access id?

Yes, if the object is public. Then you don't need any credentials. Also you can download objects with credentials if you have S3 pre-signed url for the object.

In all other cases, credentials are required in one form or the other.

Comment: Can you please share a reference link, for how to download an object from a S3 pre-signed url  of the object, if we dont have credentials ?

Comment: @John There is no special link. You just use a regular python tools to download files from url. E.g. request library. But do you have s3 pre-signed url generated for the file?

Comment: I have an open s3 bucket url of the s3 bucket image, and the image gets opened , but how to download it ?